# How to increase character limit of a particular column in xlsx sheet while exporting?

Tags: angular, npm, xlsx

I am using [npm-xlxs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#writing-options) sheet to export the data into excel sheet. But if my data is more than 255 character then it is getting truncated.

There is one writing option given(sharing code below) in the link for modifying column but it is not working out -

```
type ColInfo = {
  /* visibility */
  hidden?: boolean; // if true, the column is hidden

  /* column width is specified in one of the following ways: */
  wpx?:    number;  // width in screen pixels
  width?:  number;  // width in Excel's "Max Digit Width", width*256 is integral
  wch?:    number;  // width in characters

  /* other fields for preserving features from files */
  MDW?:    number;  // Excel's "Max Digit Width" unit, always integral
};
```

Here is the code that I have tried-

```
export(){
   let wscols = [
          {width:256},
          {width:5120},
          {width:256}
        ];
   let data:any[]=[];
   for (let i=0; i<res.length; i++){
      data.push({
         'Name' : res[i].name,
         'Comment' : res[i].comment,
         'Age' : res[i].age
      });
   }
   const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
   const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
   ws['!cols'] = wscols;
   XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Detail');
   XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'Detail_Table.xls');
}
```

Here if my comment column is greater than 255 character then it is getting truncated.

How to save the file without truncation? What parameter I am missing to set in xlsx?

Comment: unfortunately i don't have any experience regarding npm-xlxs, but did you already try to set `wch: 5120` (width in characters) additionally?

Comment: Yes, i tried that also but it was not working.